# Amazon EC2 Load balancer port 8000 to 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a amazon ec2 isntance which has a node server running on port 8000. I have created a load balancer to listen to port 8000 from port 80. This works however when I visit. http:ffew-amazon.com I get nothing but if I visit http:ffew-amazon.com:8000 I get my server. I want to have port 8000 forwarded to port 80.

Here is my configuration, hopefully someone can help

Here is my secutiry group so far

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that you have assigned a proper "Security Group", allowing external access to your LB, plus check that the given host name points to the LB's IP address not to your EC2 instance. After creating the LB look at the LB description and the DNS name.

Comment: I added what I have for my secutiry group above. Do I need to add 8000 to the secturiy group. The DNS Name in the load balance is pointing to load-balance-8000-fdsfas.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com (A Record)

Comment: check that the given host name points to the LB's IP address not to your EC2 instance. Where do I check for this?

Comment: I think you obfuscated the LB's DNS name, that's ok, but I cannot resolve DNS right now. If you resolve the correct name this will probably show multiple IP addresses depending on the availability zones you deployed the LB to. Your SG with inbound rule port 80 looks OK for me. The 8080 is for the internal forwarding to your EC2 instance. Please be aware, that you also have to allow inbound 8080 in your instance SG. Have a look at your LB, tab "Monitoring" and check that the target instance is "in service".

Comment: When you request the LB DNS name in your browser (port 80) you should get a result, maybe a HTTP 503 if your backend instance is down (out of service). If the name is not resovable there's another problem, maybe DNS related, like caching. Otherwise try to first fix DNS and then give detailed output of e.g. `curl -D - http://<lbip>`

Comment: Im dumb I didn't realazie I was supposed to visit the loadbalancer. I was visiting hte ec2 instance. Thanks it's working now